# Construct Variable Name at runtime

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to AS3 and i need a bit of help.

I have this code to play different audio files and dynamically loop them:

```
var mIntroLoop = 12495;
var mBattleLoop = 29000;
var currentPlaying;

function playMusic(x):void
{
     musicChannel = x.play();
     currentPlaying = x;
}

function loopSound(m:Object):Function {
  return function(e:Event):void {
         musicChannel = m.play(m.toString() + "Loop");
     musicChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, loopSound(currentPlaying));
  }
}

playMusic(mIntro);
musicChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, loopSound(currentPlaying));
```

As you can see on top of the code i have two variables, `mIntroLoop` and `mBattleLoop`.

I need help with this line:

```
musicChannel = m.play(m.toString() + "Loop");
```

This is not working of course, it is there just so you know what i'm trying to do.

Into that line, `m.play()` need to have as argument the returned value of either `mIntroLoop` or `mBattleLoop`, depending on what i'm currently playing.

Comment: I've solved id using Object properties.

Answer (score 0):

I see you solved it yourself, but I think you should look at this anyway.

Because all AS3 classes extend `Object` class, you can do something like this:

```
musicChannel = m.play( this[m.toString() + "Loop"] );
```

Although I don't suggest using this method, as it gets really hard to read when you come back to your code. Otherwise I think it's a clean solution.